# find cell content highlight different cell in same row

Tags: javascript, getelementsbytagname

Using the following,

```
var cells = document.getElementById("test").getElementsByTagName("td");
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    if (cells[i].innerHTML == "one") {
        cells[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Uubqg/

does anyone know how I can locate any word in a row and have it highlight a specific cell in the same row

take for instance if the word one is found anywhere, it highlights the first cell in that row?

Comment: This is a nice programming thinking puzzle. You'll have to store the first cell of every loop in a variable, and apply the red color to it, instead of `cells[i]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To highlight the first cell, just go back to the parent rows and get the cells:

```
var cells = document.getElementById("test").getElementsByTagName("td");
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    if (cells[i].innerHTML == "one") {
        var row = cells[i].parentNode;
        row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sure, just look at the cell's parentNode, and then children[0] like this:

```
var cells = document.getElementById("test").getElementsByTagName("td");
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    if (cells[i].innerHTML == "one") {
        cells[i].parentNode.firstChild.children[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}
```

working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Uubqg/47/

Comment: holy moly, i didn't know that existed. awesome. thanks!